# Will using PECL to install an extension warn me of any changes it will make?

Tags: php, linux, memcached, pear, pecl

I'm using some PHP 5.1 code that won't work with a newer version of PHP, but I would like to use the memcache extension with it.  I'm not sure if PECL will install additional packages, upgrade packages, or remove packages if I use it--and if it does I'd like to have a warning if I run the `pecl install memcache` command.  Will PECL warn me of the specific change it's going to make?  Do I have to worry about it upgrading my PHP version?  Rudimentary questions, I know, but I'm just trying to be cautious;  I've never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `pecl install memcache` I don't believe it'll install any dependencies. It definitely can't upgrade your php install/version, the pecl command only works with extensions and not with the core PHP files.

If you find that you need to install an older version of a PECL extension you can install specific versions (there's a full list of memcache releases [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache)) by specifying the version number e.g. `pecl install memcache-2.2.5`